# Mac's internal Bluetooth no longer works; is it possible to use a Bluetooth-via-USB adapter?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth

My MacBook's internal Bluetooth stopped working.* My MacBook's System Information says "no information found" under "Bluetooth". Is it possible to use some kind of USB to Bluetooth adapter to connect with the wireless Mac keyboard and Magic Mouse?

* (The problem was not solved by doing any of the highest rated tips: restarting, reinstalling, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. USB Bluetooth adapters work just fine on the Mac.